# Automatically kept-back APT packages not showing up

Tags: debian, ansible, apt

I can't list apt packages kept back by the system itself.
A have a few systems where I know there are kept-back packages.
`apt-get upgrade -s` shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-image-amd64 openjdk-11-jre-headless
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ...
```

However, when i run `apt-mark showhold` or `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` nothing is returned.

Is there any way (except for using `apt-get upgrade`) to list these packages?

When packages are kept back manually by using either `apt-mark hold <package>` or `echo "<package> hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`, the packages *do* show up.

This is a problem for me, because the python-apt module that Ansible uses, doesn't seem to honor these 'automatic' kept back packages.

I have this problem on both my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS production systems, and my Debian 10.9 lab system. Aptitude is not installed (and never was), and all systems are headless servers, so no scary GUI magic is happening.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Does [pckage_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html#ansible-builtin-package-facts-package-information-as-facts) recognise them? To move forward, [edit] you question and make the case [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: They are probably kept-back after an algorithm (in apt) deemed it wouldn't upgrade them, not because they are in the hold state. An easy method to know why they were kept back is to try to upgrade them explictly. Once you know the reason, maybe you can devise something about it with ansible.

Comment: @VladimirBotka The issue is that it's not something that can be reproduced easily, because there has to be some dependency or so, that causes apt to not upgrade the packages in certain situations. pckage_facts does list the packages, but doesn't show their held back status.

Comment: @A.B I was afraid that that would be the answer, haha. We'll probably have to do some more manual work to check out each different held back package separately then. And it is a bit unfortunate that the python-apt package that ansible uses, does not behave in the same way as apt itself.

Comment: Use [dpkg_selections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dpkg_selections_module.html#ansible-builtin-dpkg-selections-dpkg-package-selection-selections) and [apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html) modules.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I am using the apt module (which is built upon python-apt), and this is causing my problems. It doesn't recognize these kept-back packages, and installs them anyway. 

dpkg_selections uses the dpkg –get-selections and –set-selections commands (according to the docs), which don't work in this case either (as mentioned in my original question)

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**apt module ... doesn't recognize kept-back packages, and installs them anyway. dpkg_selections uses the dpkg –get-selections and –set-selections commands (according to the docs), which don't work in this case either.**"*

A: I can't reproduce the problem in Ubuntu 20.04 and Ansible 2.9.6. When I select a package to hold, e.g.

```yaml
    - dpkg_selections:
        name: tmux
        selection: hold
      tags: selection
```

the command works as expected

```sh
shell> dpkg --get-selections | grep tmux
tmux                        hold

shell> tmux -V
tmux 3.0a
```

When I try to upgrade the package, e.g.

```yaml
    - apt:
        name: tmux
        state: latest
```

the task fails

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
> cache_update_time: 1621240502
> cache_updated: false
> msg: |-
> '/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold"      install 'tmux'' failed: E: Held packages were changed and -y was used without --allow-change-held-packages.
> rc: 100
> stderr: |-
> E: Held packages were changed and -y was used without --allow-change-held-packages.
> stderr_lines: 
> stdout: |-
> Reading package lists...
> Building dependency tree...
> Reading state information...
> The following held packages will be changed:
> tmux
> The following packages will be upgraded:
> tmux
> 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
> stdout_lines:

---

When the selection is set back to install

```yaml
    - dpkg_selections:
        name: tmux
        selection: install
```

the command also works as expected

```sh
shell> dpkg --get-selections | grep tmux
tmux                        install
```

and the package can be upgraded, e.g.

```yaml
    - apt:
        name: tmux
        state: latest
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  result:
    cache_update_time: 1621240502
    cache_updated: false
    changed: true
    diff: {}
    failed: false
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: |-
      Reading package lists...
      Building dependency tree...
      Reading state information...
      The following packages will be upgraded:
        tmux
      1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.

      ...

    - Preparing to unpack .../tmux_3.0a-2ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
    - Unpacking tmux (3.0a-2ubuntu0.3) over (3.0a-2ubuntu0.2) ...
    - Setting up tmux (3.0a-2ubuntu0.3) ...
    - Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

Comment: The problem isn't about manually held back packages, it is about packages that are automatically held back by apt itself. That is why I don't think its a problem with ansible specifically, but in either the python module used by ansible, or apt itself.

Comment: ... which is not a problem of Ansible.